# Como organizar meus models na construção de um album de fotos no Django?

Tags: django

Estou construindo um álbum de fotos, mas não sei como devo organizar. Como deveriam ser meus models?

```
Class Foto(models.Model):
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to='img')

Class Album(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    fotos = models.ManyToManyField(Foto)
```

Ou assim:

```
Class Foto(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to='img')

Class Album(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: Você quer que cada foto possa pertencer a mais de um álbum ou não?

Comment: @bfavaretto nesse caso não

Comment: Eu não sei nada de django, mas parece que a diferença é somente essa: o primeiro formato define que uma foto pode estar em vários álbuns, e o segundo diz que ela pertence a um só. Mas não vou postar isso como resposta porque não tenho certeza, vou deixar para algum especialista no assunto dizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso irá depender do que você quer.

### Caso 1

Se você quer indicar que um álbum tenha *n* fotos e essas fotos podem estar em mais de um álbum, a estrutura pode ser assim:

```
# codigo 1
Class Foto(models.Model):
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to='img')

Class Album(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    fotos = models.ManyToManyField(Foto)
```

Ou assim:

```
# codigo 2
Class Foto(models.Model):
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to='img')
    albums = models.ManyToManyField(Album)

Class Album(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Em ambos os casos, você poderá filtrar os resultados dos dois lados.

**Exemplo (em relação ao código 2):**

Para pegar uma lista de fotos que tem álbum de `id` igual a `1`, você pode fazer assim:

```
album = Album.object.get(pk=1)
album.foto_set.all()
```

### Caso 2

Já em relação a estrutura abaixo, você está dizendo que uma foto pode apenas pertencer a um álbum:

```
Class Foto(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to='img')

Class Album(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

A relação pode acontecer de *Foto* para *Album* ou vice-versa. Recomendo a leitura da [Documentação do Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/), ou do [djangobook](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter10.html).